# Creating a database for foods and calorie amounts MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am going to be creating a database that will contain a list of certain foods and their calories per 100 grams.  Do I just create it the same way as I do  empty database then fill the database with the Insert tab on PHPMYADMIN?

Any advice at all would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, you do exactly that.

Comment: Great Stan, just wanted to make sure.

Comment: yeah ,if you Just want using this table for show resualt , it is best work . and you can create and modify database with phpmyadmin but if number of food is very much, you can create form with php or other language for this problem .